# Attempt to read from field 'long android.view.Surface.mNativeObject' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am struggling to identify the cause of a crash I see in my firebase crashlytics logs. I cannot replicate it and it does not seem to occur often. I know which screen it is happening on because of the crashlytics logs but am struggling to identify which component. I wonder if anyone can give me any pointers ?

Here is the full stack trace

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'long android.view.Surface.mNativeObject' on a null object reference
       at android.view.SurfaceSession.<init>(SurfaceSession.java:40)
       at android.widget.Magnifier$InternalPopupWindow.<init>(Magnifier.java:498)
       at android.widget.Magnifier.show(Magnifier.java:175)
       at android.widget.Editor$MagnifierMotionAnimator.show(Editor.java:4411)
       at android.widget.Editor$MagnifierMotionAnimator.access$6100(Editor.java:4354)
       at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.updateMagnifier(Editor.java:4925)
       at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:5122)
       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12521)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
       at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:2407)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12760)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5490)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5294)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4799)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4852)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4818)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4958)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4826)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5015)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4799)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4852)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4818)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4826)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4799)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7485)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7454)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7415)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7588)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:187)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6791)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
```

Appreciate any assistance

The device details are as follows:

Brand:Urovo
Model:DT50Q
Version:Android 9
RAM free: 2.17 GB
Disk free: 45.07 GB